# What is the difference between (expression) and (command) in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

Are there any meaningfull difference between a command and an expression in bash scripting?
Also, I know (command) opens a  new subshell and runs the command,
but what i dont know is what happens when you have (expression). What happens when you an expression instead of a command.

eg

```
[[ ( "$#" < 1 ) ]]
```

Thanks

Comment: Unless you have a command called `2+3`, you will get a "command not found" error. I don't think I fully understand the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda I sometimes see if (2+3) then.....  question is does (expresion) behave differently in conditional tests?

Comment: In what way is the example in your script not using a command within `(...)`? It looks like a command to me. A compound command consisting of an OR-list and two uses of the `[` utility, to be precise.

Comment: @Kusalananda i see it now

Comment: Ok, you keep changing the example. It's difficult to write an answer. Will you hold it for a bit?

Comment: @Kusalananda what about the new example...is e new subshell created for ("$#" < 1) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
[[ ( "$#" < 1 ) ]]
```

This is a `[[ ... ]]` test that checks whether `$#`, the number of positional parameters, sort before `1` lexicographically (use `-lt` in place of `<`  to perform an arithmetic "less than" test).

Within the special `[[ ... ]]` syntax in the `bash` shell, the parentheses do not introduce a sub-shell but rather provide a way of grouping expressions in order to override the normal precedence of operators.

This is explained in the `bash` manual, where it describes the `[[ ... ]]` syntax:

> `[[ expression ]]`
>
> [...]
>
> Expressions may be combined using the following operators,
> listed in decreasing order of precedence:
>
> `( expression )`
> Returns the value of `expression`.  This may be used to
> override the normal precedence of operators.
> [...etc...]

Comment: Thanks a lot...its now very clear....